# Why this Arduino sscanf JSON parsing problem?

Tags: json, string, arduino, scanf

I am trying to parse this JSON string:

{"FN":"142","SName":"stil.mp3","InPlaylist1":"1","InPlaylist2":"1","error":0}
I use this sscan statement:

' RetScanf = sscanf(OneJsonStr, "{\"FN\":\"%d\",\"SName\":\"%[^\"],\"InPlaylist1\":\"%d\",\"InPlaylist2\":\"%d\",\"error\":%d}", &Parameter1_FNo, Parameter2_FName, InP1, InP2, &err); '

but in only parses the two first parameter "FN" and "SName". any idea what I am doing wrong?

thnaks in advance
br.
Allan

Comment: what are the parameter types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sscanf() format, when matching the SName string, you never try to match the trailing double quote.

```
  ,\"SName\":\"%[^\"]\",
```

Also, since the format says that InP1/2 are integers, you should pass in their addresses (assuming they aren't already pointers).

Comment: thanks you are right I chnged InP1 to &InP1 and InP2 to &InP2